# How to read this JProfiler comparison correctly?

Tags: java, comparison, jprofiler

I've just started to use JProfiler 11.1. I used it to benchmark the memory consumption of my system, before and after the code changed. I saved them into two screenshots and I made a comparison from them. This may sound silly but in the result chart, I cannot understand what does it mean. In the left side bare, I have after-6.jps before before6.jsp, and in the comparison result, I see a lot of red bars which rise toward the right side. Does it mean, "after-6.jps" has MORE than "before-6.jsp", or the vice versa?

I did some Googling but couldn't find any article about how to read it.
Any help would be appreciated!
[image: How to read this comparison]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the snapshot selector, the snapshots that are part of the selected comparison are labelled with numbers, for a dual comparison like the objects comparison, the labels are "1" and "2". The displayed differences are calculated as

```
(measurement in snapshot 2) - (measurement in snapshot 1)
```

so in your case "before-6.jps" contains more strings that "after-6.jps". You would probably like to see this the other way around, so you can select the snapshots differently in the first step of the comparison wizard. The comparison wizard orders the snapshot by default in the same order as they appear in the snapshot selector, so I would reccomend to reorder the snapshots there so that "before-6.jps" comes before "after-6.jps".

Comment: Thank you. That's what I looked for :)